# ASP.NET link to file within solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just inherited a web forms application and I'm trying to create a link to a file that is stored within the application. We have several PDF reports that are stored in a "reports" folder within the content folder.  I set up the link as such:

```
<asp:HyperLink id="hl1" 
    NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Content/reports/{0}.pdf",Eval("reportTitle")) %>' 
    Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "reportTitle")%>' 
    Target="_blank"
    runat="server" />
```

When I hover over the link it points to localhost:3016/Content/Reports/reportName.pdf but when the page comes up there is a 404 error.  I'm more used to doing this in MVC, which was a snap, but can't seem to get this to work.

EDIT

This is the URL when I navigate to the file from the browser

file:///D:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/OE/Content/reports/2012_report.pdf

This is what is displays the 404 error

http://localhost:3106/Content/reports/2012_report.pdf

Comment: Probably an IIS configuration issue.  Make sure you have mapped the ,pdf extension and the appropriate MIME type. [Link](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap)

Comment: this seems to be a problem not of the ASP markup or codebehind, but of the hosting. Can you try switch from visual studio built-in server (which port 3016 indicates you are using) to local IIS, and check the mapping of the virtual path?

Comment: Please update your post to specify whether you are using IIS in integrated pipeline or classic mode.  Could affect the answer.

Comment: This is all from my local

Comment: Maybe using `file://`

Comment: What does the URL point to when you actually run it? What URL do you want it to point to?

Comment: Try navigating to the file manually in your browser, do you still get 404?

Comment: This is the URL when I navigate to the file from the browser

file:///D:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/OE/Content/reports/2012_report.pdf

http://localhost:3106/Content/reports/2012_report.pdf

Comment: Okay, this is really embarrassing but I didn't realize that when they entered the data they replaced spaces with underscores.  Not sure why they didn't keep it the same, thanks to everyone for contributing.